# How to get the additional "Show similar placements" link in placement ideas in the display planner

Tags: google-adsense, google-ads

In the Adwords Display Planner under "Placement ideas" some websites have an additional  "Show similar placements" link under which the custom channels of this website (with allowed targeting) are shown.

I have created custom channels for my websites ( with targeting allowed), but those links are still missing for my sites.

- My websites are showing up in the placement ideas (but without those similar placement links)
- The custom channels have all more than 1k views per day.
- I waited for more than one week after creating the custom channels.

Comment: Have you tried to contact Adsense support?